# Finding my HTTP POST URL using Wampserver

Tags: php, android, url, http-post

I'm trying to post images from my android application to php Wampserver.

The server side script is in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.4.5\android\base.php

My http post URL on my app is : "http://"ip address"/android/base.php"

Is this incorrect?

Comment: yes! it should work with in your domain.

Comment: it really depends on your apache config no? If you type http://localhost/android/base.php on your wampp server what do you get?

Comment: If you don't know how your server is configured, then how would we?

Comment: @jribeiro I saved my base.php elsewhere so now my code shows up when I type localhost/android/base.php

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Any idea how I can find out the configurations and what I'm meant to look for?

Comment: So you should be fine! :) Try searching for httpd.conf you should have virtual host configured or something

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/

Comment: @jribeiro Is the ip address meant to be my laptop ip address?

Comment: Anyway, it sounds a bit strange that you placed your android application under the phpmyadmin directory. That directory coud have some .htpaccess directive which does not allow your code to work as expected. I would suggest you to move your android directory outside the phpmyadmin directory.

Comment: @jap1968 I don't have my android app installed in the phpmyadmin directory, I agree that is quite strange..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My URL was correct, I just hadn't connected my Android device to my wireless network.
http://mrjoelkemp.com/2011/06/android-physical-device-connection-to-local-pc-wamp-server/

Answer (score 0):

Well let's break this in parts...

First: You need a fixed ip/domain to access your computer from the web. If your public ip keeps changing this is no good (i'm referring to public ip... different from private network which is normally 192.168...)

If you don't have fixed ip you can use a service like http://www.no-ip.com/

Second: Once you have first step covered, you'll need to make sure the routing is taken care...

You should be behind a router (i guess) and you'll have to set your laptop to fixed ip and add rules in router to forward all request on port 80 to your laptop fixed ip

Third: Test to check if it's working... Your base apache conf might work as it is. If it's not you can read how to configure it in:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html

Hope this helps... If not please tell

Note: You may have to configure your laptop firewall (if any installed)